# Is it possible to take a value from a class and use that as a variable name addition?

Tags: python, class

So I have this very basic code:

```
USER_COUNT = 0


class User:
    def __init__(self, username, age):
        global USER_COUNT
        USER_COUNT += 1
        self.id = USER_COUNT
        self.username = username
        self.age = age


user_1 = User(input('What is your name?:  '), input('How old are you?:  '))

print(user_1.username, user_1.age, user_1.id)
```

The important thing about this code is the user id which is generated based on how many people use the code. I want to make it so that the id is also the variable. ie: the user with the id of 3 with have the variable name user_3 without me having to name it manually and just add as many people as possible all with different variable names. I do not want to change previous variable values simply to set the user number = user id.

Is this possible in Python? If so how would you go about doing it?

Comment: Just as an aside; please dont use global variables. There are other ways of doing what you are thinking. I assume you are still in the process of learning how to write code, But doing it like this will hurt down the line. A good post about it can be found here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/2hqkpl/is_it_bad_to_use_global_variables/

Comment: @CasperBang Thank you. You are correct I have only been learning coding for 4 or so months so far. Why are global variables not used? I thought global variables where just used as things that should never change? Or do coders just solely use local scope? Thank you for being helpful and not toxic!

Comment: So in reality when you'd have a user, you'd probably have it in a database. Most database technologies would have something like  `AUTO INCREMENT`, and therefore you'd never write the ID yourself. You'd set it to null and make the database set the value for you (automatically incrementing the prior ID with 1), and return that. But in a case like yours, I'd probably create a UserFactory that creates the user and then limit the scope of the `USER_COUNT` to the Factory. 

Global variables are unpredictable, horrible in async code, and impede your testing capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an unspecified amount of users, and want something like this, then you should probably use an [array](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp). I.e something like this:

```py
users = []
users[0] = User(input('What is your name?:  '), input('How old are you?:  '))
```

If you want to add for instance 5 users you could do:

```py
users = []
for i in range(5):
   users[i] = User(input('What is your name?:  '), input('How old are you?:  '))

for user in users:
   print(user.username, user.age, user.id)
```

If you want to add keep adding users until some case happens, I'd probably do something like this:

```py
users = []
while True:
   users[i] = User(input('What is your name?:  '), input('How old are you?:  '))

   if('y' not in input('Add another user? [(y)es/(n)o]:   ').lower()
      break

for user in users:
   print(user.username, user.age, user.id)
```

To explain the above code a bit, a `while` loop will do something until X happens. In this case I wanted, what other languages call a 'do while' loop, but it doesn't exist in python, so we do a `while true` (infinite loop), and then have an if statement at the end, that will `break` (exit) the loop when something happens. There we check whether the user writes something with a `y` in it (`y`,  `yes`, `yes please`, `yup` `yir me matey` etc would work). I use the `.lower()` to take the input that is written, and make it lowercase - this makes it possible to catch both `yes`, and `YES` or `Yes`, turning any of those strings into `yes`.